# Need assistance with Min and Max function?

Tags: java

I have an application a number guess game, users have to guess a number between 0 and 100, when they guess right the program asks them if they would like to play again when their done play I display the least number of guesses in a game and the greatest number of guess in a game. Right now all i get is the sum of all their guesses in the when using the "Math.min(,)"?
How do I get the minimum function to work??? the function code is in further below.

1. **leastNumGuesses = Math.min(leastNumGuesses,guesses);**

   ```
   double rightNum = Math.random() *100;
   int randomNum = (int) rightNum; //convert the random number to int
   int tries = 0; //single game gussess output
   int numberOfGames = 0;
   int allTries = 0; //accumalates all tries(sum of all tries)
   int guesses = 0; // guesses of all games combined
   int gameGuesses = 0;
   int leastNumGuesses = 100;
   int mostNumGuesses = 0;


     while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
   ```

   {

   ```
      System.out.println();

      int guess = getIntWithinRange(sc,"Enter the Number: ", 0, 100);
      tries++;
      guesses++;
      gameGuesses++;

      if (guess == randomNum)
      {
          numberOfGames++;
          System.out.println("You got it in " + tries + " tries.");
          leastNumGuesses = Math.min(leastNumGuesses,gameGuesses);
          if (tries <=3)
                   System.out.println("Great work! You are a mathematical wizard.");
          else if (tries > 3 && tries <= 7)
                   System.out.println("Not too bad! You've got some potential.");
          else if (tries > 7)
                   System.out.println("What took you so long? Maybe you should take some lessons.");

          System.out.println();      
          System.out.println("Would you like to play again (y/n):");
          choice = sc.nextLine();

      while (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n") && !choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
       {

      System.out.println("Error! entry must be \"y\" or \"n\".");
      System.out.println("Would you like to play again (y/n):");
      choice = sc.nextLine();
       }   

          if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))       
          {    // reset the random number & tries

             rightNum = Math.random() *100;
               randomNum = (int) rightNum;
               tries=0;
              gameGuesses++;
          }
          else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
          {    
             allTries += guesses;
             int averageNumGuess = allTries / numberOfGames;

              System.out.println("Bye - Come back again");
              System.out.println("Number of Games Played: " + numberOfGames);
              System.out.println("Average Number of Guesses: " + averageNumGuess);
              System.out.println("Least Amount of Guesses In a Single Game: " + leastNumGuesses);

          }

      }
   ```

Comment: Could you post a minimal code snip that 1) demonstrates the problem and 2) is compilable?

Comment: What happens when you compile and run your code? How does it differ from what you want and expect?

Comment: @Code-Guru  it adds all the guesses together for each game and displays it as the least number of guesses in a single game; I want it to take all the guesses in every game and find the smallest or least amount of guesses in a game.

Comment: I suggest you use a debugger or add System.out.println() calls to your code to figure out why it behaves the way it does.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're changing what you want `guesses` to stand for in the middle of the program.

Remember that `guesses` is the ***total*** number of guesses over all games played, and that `leastNumGuesses` is initially set to `100`.  In most cases, you will find that `guesses < leastNumGuesses`, and thus the `Math.min(guesses, leastNumGuesses)` function will return `guesses`.

To fix: use variable other than `guesses`, for example, `gameGuesses` to keep track of how many guesses were made in a game.  Then, `Math.min(,)` will behave as you expect.

Comment: I tried that but the issue stands the min function adds the all the guesses together, Perhaps am putting the variable in the wrong place? i don't know but this is really bugging me.

Comment: @user1852564 put the `Math.min(guesses, leastNumGuesses)` line inside the loop so that it executes every time the game ends, regardless of whether the user answers "y" or "n".